# How to get my lost Xperia SL back even after factory reset?

Tags: google-account, lost-phone, android-device-manager

I'm new to this forum, I have lost my Xperia SL yesterday in a bus. I have registered police complaint with my IMEI number. I was trying to locate the phone using android device manager when someone uses my phone's internet. so far nothing is going correct.

When i log in to the google play with my email-id, my mobile phone model has been showing.

I have a doubt that, when the thief does a factory reset, and sign in using a new account in google play, will i able to still detect my phone with its registered model number? 
will i able to track my mobile with any of the technology? (I have not installed any tracking apps in my mobile).
or i have to wait for the police to track it with my imei number?

Can anyone help me to clear my doubts?

I have not changed my password of my gmail, so that i may have the more possibilites of tracking my device.

Comment: As soon as the device gets factory-reset, you can forget about tracking it with Google's Device Manager: As your Google Account on the device is gone then, there's no way for Google's DM to communicate with it.

Comment: So the only way i can track it once my phone is factory reset is with the help of the police with my imei number!!!!

Comment: Yes. Unless you've installed some anti-theft solution which integrates with the ROM (and thus survices a factory-reset). But even that would be gone as soon as a new ROM is flashed. As long as it's still working, you could take a second device and follow the lost one. Once in range that you should be able to see it, you could trigger the 5-minutes-permanent-ringer. In the hope for an "honest finder", who should take this as a proof and hand your device back to you. Don't wait too long, or the battery might be dead.

Comment: @Izzy Why is this a comment and not an answer?

Comment: Good point. Summed up everything and made it an answer. Thanks for the heads-up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As soon as the device gets factory-reset, you can forget about tracking it with Google's [Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager): As your Google Account on the device is gone then, there's no way for Google's DM to communicate with it.

Unless you've installed some anti-theft solution which integrates with the ROM (and thus survices a factory-reset – a feature offered e.g. by [Cerberus](http://www.appbrain.com/app/Cerberus-Anti-Diebstahl/com.lsdroid.cerberus), if your device is rooted), you will have lost all control then. But even a ROM-integrated solution would be gone as soon as a new ROM is flashed.

As long as it's still working, you could take a second device and follow the lost one. Once in range that you should be able to see it, you could trigger the 5-minutes-permanent-ringer. In the hope for an "honest finder", who should take this as a proof and hand your device back to you.

Don't wait too long, or the battery might be dead!